# want to add vertical line between tabs in createMeterialTopTabNavigator

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Hy.
I am replicating an app. I am using createMeterialTopTabNavigator. The rest of functionality is working fine. I want to show a vertical line between tabs. but I have no idea where to get started. Please help me.
I want the tabs to show a similar line like the one in the image.

here is my code

```
import { Text, View} from 'react-native';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';

import {
  createBottomTabNavigator,
  createMaterialTopTabNavigator
} from "react-navigation-tabs";
import{createAppContainer,NavigationContainer} from "react-navigation";
import ArenaCashScreen from './Screens/ArenaCashScreen';
import ArenaPointsScreen from './Screens/ArenaPointsScreen';
import UnknownCashScreen from './Screens/UnknownCashScreen';



const MainTabs = createMaterialTopTabNavigator(
      { 
        CurrentList: {
          screen: ArenaCashScreen,
          navigationOptions: {
            title: 'Arena Cash (AC)',
          },
        },
        OthersList: {
          screen: ArenaPointsScreen,
          navigationOptions: {
            title: 'Arena Points (AP)',
          },
        },
        thirdlistt: {
          screen: UnknownCashScreen,
          navigationOptions: {
            title: 'Unknown Cash (UC)',
          },
        },
      },
      {
        tabBarOptions: {
                activeTintColor:'white',
                inactiveTintColor:'white',
                indicatorStyle: {
                    backgroundColor: 'orange',
                  },
              style: {
                backgroundColor: 'black',
                elevation:0, // remove shadow on Android
                shadowOpacity: 0, // remove shadow on iOS,
                borderWidth:1,
                borderColor:'black'
              },
          showLabel: true,
          showIcon: false,
        },
      },
    );
    
const AppContainer2 = createAppContainer(MainTabs);

export default AppContainer2;
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by adding the css style to the tabs.

For this you just open the **inspect** by clicking **F12** and find out the class used for the styling for showing the title and div containing these titles.

Once you find the class, add the **border-left** by applying the other required sytle like color and width as well as border style.

Comment: thanks for the answer. Maybe the question is not clear. I am working on a react-native app.

Answer (score 0):

It can be achieved using `tabBarItemStyle` property. However, it will add the vertical line on each Tab-bar Item, but in my case vertical line with last item won't show, it works fine

```
<Tab.Navigator 
     
     screenOptions={{
      tabBarItemStyle:{borderRightWidth:1,height:Height*0.08,borderRightColor:'red'}, 
     }}
    >
{/*Your Tab Screens*/}
</Tab.Navigator>
```